# listing undefined symbols in plugins

Tags: c, linux, linker, dlopen, ldd

usually, when developing libraries/application, one can use the `ldd` program to check external dependencies (linked in dynamic libraries) and undefined symbols:

```
 $ ldd -r libfoo.so
 linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff6b9fe000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa55fe31000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa55fa85000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa560386000)
 libbar.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libbar.so.0
 undefined symbol: bar_nullfn (libfoo.so)
```

so this example seem to have an incompatible version of *libbar.so* installed, which lacks the `bar_nullfn`. this will seldomly happen on the machine that was used to build `libfoo.so`, as the linker will already complain about missing symbols during the build phase.

this works great, as long as the runtime linker can resolve the symbols (or not) based on the information in `libfoo.so`

unfortunately i'm working with *plugins*, that dynamic libraries that are dlopen()ed by a host application. these plugins use functions from the host application (exposed via a header) but which cannot be resolved outside the context of the host.
naturally, running `ldd -r` gives me tons of *false positives*:

```
 $ ldd -r ./foo.so
 linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff6b9fe000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa55fe31000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa55fa85000)
 undefined symbol: post             (./foo.so)
 undefined symbol: startpost        (./foo.so)
 undefined symbol: clock_free       (./foo.so)
 undefined symbol: clock_new        (./foo.so)
 undefined symbol: logpost          (./foo.so)
 undefined symbol: clock_set        (./foo.so)
```

since the host provides those symbols (`post`,...), the plugin can be dlopen()ed even though it seems to have so many undefined symbols.

the linker is explicitely instructed, to ignore missing symbols, in order to be able to bulid such plugins.

now my problem is, that *sometimes* such a plugin has indeed an undefined symbol, which cannot be resolved during runtime.
since he linker was asked to ignore missing symbols during the build, no warning is issued.
but when the plugin is loaded, `dlopen()` fails with something like

```
 undefined symbol: psot
```

ldd gives me:

```
 $ ldd -r ./foo.so
 linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff6b9fe000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa55fe31000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa55fa85000)
 undefined symbol: post             (./foo.so)
 undefined symbol: startpost        (./foo.so)
 undefined symbol: logpsot          (./foo.so)
 undefined symbol: clock_free       (./foo.so)
 undefined symbol: clock_new        (./foo.so)
 undefined symbol: psot             (./foo.so)
 undefined symbol: logpost          (./foo.so)
 undefined symbol: clock_set        (./foo.so)
```

currently the only way i know how to fix that, is by iteratively fix each missing symbol.
e.g. if i made two typos in my plugin, using the (nonexistant) functions `psot()` and `logpsot()`,  istart my host, load the plugin, discover that i used the symbol `psot`, fix the problem, recompile, restart the host/plugin, only to discover that i also wrote `logpsot`.

i was wondering whether there is a way to specify additional binary objects that can be used to resolve symbols with `ldd` (or similar).
e.g.

```
 ldd --addlib /path/to/host -r ./foo.so
 $ ldd -r ./foo.so
 linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff6b9fe000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa55fe31000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa55fa85000)
 undefined symbol: logpsot          (./foo.so)
 undefined symbol: psot             (./foo.so)
```

Comment: As a workaround, you can try providing weak stub instances of the symbols that will be provided by the application hosting the application, and require the plugin to link against the stubs.

Comment: Or you can write your own script to extract the symbols from the object & library files with `nm`, and try to sort out yourself which symbols are missing.